How to end a `code` block when truncating a GitHub Pages post?
I'm attempting to use GitHub pages to publish some posts, and I want the home page to show some content from the most recent 3 posts. I'm doing so using:
  <div class="entries">
  {% for post in site.posts limit:5 %}
    <div>
        <a href="{{ post.url }}"><h3>{{ post.title }}</h3></a>
        <p class="blogdate">{{ post.date | date: "%d %B %Y" }}</p>
        <div>{{ post.content | truncatehtml | truncatewords: 60 }}</div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>

The truncation logic is whatever GitHub Pages supplies by default, or in the Cayman  theme. The syntax used came from this question.
It's mostly doing what I want, but falls down if the truncation decides to happen while a <code> block is open, which ruins the styling for any posts that follow.
What would be the correct way to truncate a post while also ensuring no open tags go un-closed?

Have you looked into post excerpts?

sounds like a bug in truncatehtml. you could instead do post.content | strip_html | truncate see https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/strip_html/

I had seen mention of excerpts, but it sounded like a 3rd-party plugin which was something I didn't want to get involved in. Turns out it's actually built-in.

In this situation, strip_html sort of causes the opposite problem - it ends up rendering what should have been in a code block as ordinary text.
